# How to redirect user if a linkid belong to certain Catid

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, redirect, header

I wrote this script , but no redirect , so what is the problem
please assist me asap

```
<?php   
include('config.php');   

$number = intval($_POST['catid']);   
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sound_link WHERE linkid =$linkid");   
$check = $rows["catid"];
if ($check = 3)  
    {  
        echo '<B>..You will go to audio.php page.....................';  
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=AUDIO.php?linkid=$linkid'>";  
    echo mysql_error();  

        }else{  
echo '.... You will stay text.php page'; 

    }  
?>
<php include 'text.php' ;?>
```

and I ask if I want to use header function instead of meta refresh

please kidly find a mistake I made in code

THANKS

Comment: I re-tagged your question - you should get some more eyes on it now :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I cannot see `$linkid` variable set on your script and you got a mistake on `if ($check = 3)` line. you just defined $check variable as 3 there. change that line with `if ($check == 3)` and where did you set $rows variable?

Answer (score 1):

For the redirect to work, the best way to do is by HTTP Redirect, which means you have to redefine the HTTP Header.

You can get more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
Also note that, for the header function work without problem, you should do the redirect BEFORE you output any html code to the user, so, this MUST happen before any "echo" or php end tag ?> followed by any html content.

You should also not output any content after this, which means you should do the following:

```
 header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
 exit; // this makes sure your script execution ends here
```

Your question is not clear enough, but if I understood, redirect is not your only problem, you are using a $linkid variable inside a SQL query without defining it first.

Your snippet have also a potential SQL Injection flaw, you should read about it before interpolating variables with SQL queries. mysql_real_escape_string could be of some help, please read it before putting your code on production: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php